# OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3009,109,109,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica0/task:0/device:GPU0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:Conv2D]

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, out-of-memory

i am trying to extract features from my cnn model and train it by svm classifier here's my model:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Xception(weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3),include_top=False))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(4096,activation='relu',name='fc1'))
model.add(Dense(4096,activation='relu',name='fc2'))
model.add(Dense(1000,activation='relu',name='fc3'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',name='fc4'))
model.layers[0].trainable=False
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.001),metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=10,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),verbose=1)
```

and here's how i tried to extract the features

```
model.pop()
feature_mapping=model(x_train)
```

so whenever i try to extract the features it gives me this error

```
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3009,109,109,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:Conv2D]
```

on this line of code

```
feature_mapping=model(x_train)
```

so how can i solve that i tried to decrease the batch size and increase steps per epoch but it didn't work out either

Comment: Perhaps decrease the dtype of the array.  For example, use `float16` rather than the default `float64`. This has worked for us in the past.

Comment: use model.predict, calling the model like that expects a batch of data, not a full dataset.  predict will build batches and not run out of memory.